# Using a definition of an improper double integral over the xy-plane as a square whose sides increase to infinity

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

**Textbook problem (quoted):** An equivalent definition of the improper integral in
part (a) is

$$
\iint_{\mathbb{R}^{2}} e^{-\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)} d A=\lim _{a \rightarrow \infty} \iint_{S_{a}} e^{-\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)} d A
$$

where $S_a$ is the square with vertices $(\pm a, \pm a)$. Use this to
show that

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}} d x \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^{2}} d y=\pi.
$$

**Question:** Do I evaluate this integral directly somehow?  Note that this is part (b) of the problem.  In part (a) the improper integral of the same function was defined over the entire $xy$-plane, but instead using a disk with radius $a$, not a square, and I was able to use polar coordinates to show that the answer was $\pi$. Am I suppose to use the fact that I already know the answer to be $\pi$? Note that the left-hand side of the result they want me to show seems clear assuming that the individual impropers exist, so why is this square definition of the improper integral really needed to obtain the result?

**Textbook:** Calculus (Early Transcendentals) by James Stewart, 9th edition.  Section 15.3 on double integrals using polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the purpose of the exercise is to have you write the integral over $\Bbb{R}^2$ in two different ways and compare the results. First, as a limit over disks, then change to polar coordinates and use an elementary version of Fubini to get $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dA=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-r^2}\,r\,d\theta\,dr$.

As a second step, they want you to calculate the double integral as a limit over squares, so that you can then an elementary version of Fubini:
\begin{align}
\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dA&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{S_a}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dA\\
&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^a\int_{-a}^ae^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}\,dx\,dy\\
&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\int_{-a}^ae^{-t^2}\,dt\right)^2\\
&=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt\right)^2.
\end{align}
Then, finally, compare these two approaches to figure out what $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt$ is.

This limiting procedure of using disks first, followed by squares may seem redundant (and it is, if one has proven sufficiently general versions of the change of variables theorem and Fubini's theorem). However, my guess is that in Stewart's book, such general versions of the theorems have not been established. Hence, following the approach of the book, it may be necessary to be slightly more elaborate with the reasoning.

But just to be explicit: no, we cannot evaluate in terms of 'elementary functions', the integral over the square.

Comment: So should I assume that the two definitions lead to the same answer?  In other words, I really would use the fact that by part (a) the answer to the improper integral, however defined, is $\pi$?

Comment: @UngarLinski yes, they do lead to the same answer. On the one hand (part a), using disks, you figure out that $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dA=\pi$. On the other hand (part b), using squares, you figure out that $\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt\right)^2=\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dA$. And finally, putting these together, one arrives at the famous Gaussian integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt=\sqrt{\pi}$.